Magento 2.4 CMS Blocks dont show up on category pages
i cant get the  cms block to show up on categories pages. the same cms block works fine  on the homepage. the category page is set to display static block and product added the cms block. i do have a custom theme. any one can help with this.

what happens when you switch to luma theme ?

looks like it works in Luma theme
